# how to set current image location in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I set the current image location in vb.net if I use the drag and drop even.
It seems like the imagelocation doesn't work because I tried outputting the image location using messagebox. But it didn't show up anything. How do I get the image location of the file that I have just drop into the picturebox so that I could transfer it on another directory?

```
Private Sub pb_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles pb.DragDrop
            Dim FileToMove As String
            Dim MoveLocation As String
            Try
                pb.Image = Image.FromFile(CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), Array).GetValue(0).ToString)



                FileToMove = pb.ImageLocation


                MoveLocation = "C:\pics\" + TextBox1.Text + ".jpg" '"

                If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToMove) = True Then
                    System.IO.File.Move(FileToMove, MoveLocation)

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error Doing Drag/Drop")
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: Separate from your question, but use Path.Combine("C:\pics", textbox1.text + ".jpg").  Also abstract out the "C:\pics" part to a configuration element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you save `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), Array).GetValue(0).ToString` to a variable? That is the file path you are looking for. Not sure why `ImageLocation` property does not work here.

Comment: FileToMove = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), Array).GetValue(0).ToString  -it wouldn't work if I do this